# Render <li> with childs using nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Currently I am trying to render a menu with sub menus. As you guys can see I can have sub menus with sub menus too. I was able to create a JavaScript

This is what I have right now

```
  $scope.menu = [
            {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home', title: 'Home', path: '/', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs: []
            },

            {
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home', title: 'Reporting', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs:
                    [
                    { title: 'Compensation Report', path: '/Reports/Compensation', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: false, childs: [] },
                    { title: 'Representative Level Report', path: '/Reports/AgentId', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: false, childs: [] },
                    { title: 'Territory Report', path: '/Reports/Territory', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: false, childs: [] },
                    {  title: 'Reporting Access', path: '/Reports/Acces', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: false, childs: [] }
                    ]
            },
{ icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-home', title: 'Administrator', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs:
            [
                { title: 'Users', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs:
                [
                     { title: 'Users managment', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs: [] },
                        { title: 'Invite user', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs: [] },
                        { title: 'Create user account', path: '', tile: false, fn: null, allowAll: true, childs: [] }
                ]
                },
            ]}];
```

This is the Javascript I am using to render the menu but it only renders the some menu items so I think I need to render the child sub menus

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-bigfont" style="border-width: 0">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                        <li class="portal-text-19b" ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: hightlight === item.title && item.path !== '#'}" ng-show="showItem(item.path, item.allowAll)">
                            <a href="{{item.path}}" ng-click="item.fn()">
                                <span class="{{item.icon}}"></span>&nbsp;
                                {{item.title}}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

Comment: what actually is your problem here?

Comment: I am able to use the ng-repeat but It only renders Home, Reporting and Administrator, I dont know how to use another ng-repeat inside my current ng-repeat to render the childs sub menus

Comment: well, the same way you've done it for the first time: `ng-repeat="subitem in item.childs"`. Also consider using `ng-if` to show submenu only if there are any child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple! Inside your current `ng-repeat` which is `ng-repeat="item in menu"`, you can have another one of those. Something like,

```
  <li class="portal-text-19b" ng-repeat="item in menu" ...>
    <a href="{{item.path}}" ng-click="item.fn()">
      <span class="{{item.icon}}"></span>{{item.title}}
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="child in item.childs">
        {{child.title}}
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="child2 in child.childs">
            {{child2.title}}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

Now, since this has slightly duplicated HTML, you might want to consider creating a template and use it by having `ng-include` which would be useful in case you want to make this dynamic till `N` levels.

[**working plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wk1K4SRSrHFtTvRapMjX?p=preview)